# mysql stored procedure inconsistently increments all records

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure as I want to have a scenario where I want to get the next number from Database.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `INCREMENT_IDENTIFIERS`(IN key_name varchar(30))
BEGIN
    SET @keyName := key_name;
    UPDATE APS_IDENTIFIERS SET COUNTER = COUNTER + 1 WHERE KEY_NAME = @keyName;
    SELECT * FROM APS_IDENTIFIERS WHERE KEY_NAME = @keyName;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**Initial Column Values**

[image: Initial value before calling stored procedure]

**Final Column Values after calling stored procedure**

```
call INCREMENT_IDENTIFIERS('urn');
```

[image: Final Column Values after calling stored procedure]

**Now my problem is that why this stored procedure increments both rows even if I am passing the exact match input condition, and it return both rows as output with incremented values.**

Comment: It's not necessary to use a [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), can use the input parameter or a [13.6.4.1 Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html).

Comment: @wchiquito can you please elaborate, actually I need to call this procedure from my Java Code. Hence I need to define a User Defined Variable for a particular key I want to increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to use a [9.4 User-Defined Variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), can use the input parameter or a [13.6.4.1 Local Variable DECLARE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html):

```sql
mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `INCREMENT_IDENTIFIERS`(
    ->   `in_key_name` VARCHAR(30)
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    ->   UPDATE `APS_IDENTIFIERS`
    ->   SET `COUNTER` = `COUNTER` + 1
    ->   WHERE `KEY_NAME` = `in_key_name`;
    ->   SELECT `KEY_NAME`, `COUNTER`
    ->   FROM `APS_IDENTIFIERS`
    ->   WHERE `KEY_NAME` = `in_key_name`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `INCREMENT_IDENTIFIERS`('urn');
+----------+---------+
| KEY_NAME | COUNTER |
+----------+---------+
| urn      |       3 |
+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sEmVw1Es3tDD9KNhuG9yLw/0).

**UPDATE**

Avoid using column names as parameter names:

```sql
mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `INCREMENT_IDENTIFIERS`(
    ->   `key_name` VARCHAR(30) -- CHANGE NAME
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SET @`keyName` := `key_name`;
    ->   UPDATE `APS_IDENTIFIERS`
    ->   SET `COUNTER` = `COUNTER` + 1
    ->   WHERE `KEY_NAME` = @`keyName`;
    ->   SELECT `KEY_NAME`, `COUNTER`
    ->   FROM `APS_IDENTIFIERS`
    ->   WHERE `KEY_NAME` = @`keyName`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `INCREMENT_IDENTIFIERS`('urn');
+------------+---------+
| `KEY_NAME` | COUNTER |
+------------+---------+
| urn        |      69 |
| urn        |       3 |
+------------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

New parameter name:

```sql
mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `INCREMENT_IDENTIFIERS`(
    ->   `_key_name` VARCHAR(30) -- NEW NAME
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SET @`keyName` := `_key_name`;
    ->   UPDATE `APS_IDENTIFIERS`
    ->   SET `COUNTER` = `COUNTER` + 1
    ->   WHERE `KEY_NAME` = @`keyName`;
    ->   SELECT `KEY_NAME`, `COUNTER`
    ->   FROM `APS_IDENTIFIERS`
    ->   WHERE `KEY_NAME` = @`keyName`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `INCREMENT_IDENTIFIERS`('urn');
+----------+---------+
| KEY_NAME | COUNTER |
+----------+---------+
| urn      |       3 |
+----------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sEmVw1Es3tDD9KNhuG9yLw/1).

Check documentation [13.6.4.2 Local Variable Scope and Resolution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html).

**UPDATE 2**

Another option (less recommended) is to use qualified column names (`APS_IDENTIFIERS.KEY_NAME`):

```sql
mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `INCREMENT_IDENTIFIERS`(
    ->   `key_name` VARCHAR(30)
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SET @`keyName` := `key_name`;
    ->   UPDATE `APS_IDENTIFIERS`
    ->   SET `COUNTER` = `COUNTER` + 1
    ->   WHERE `APS_IDENTIFIERS`.`KEY_NAME` = @`keyName`;
    ->   SELECT `KEY_NAME`, `COUNTER`
    ->   FROM `APS_IDENTIFIERS`
    ->   WHERE `APS_IDENTIFIERS`.`KEY_NAME` = @`keyName`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;

mysql> CALL `INCREMENT_IDENTIFIERS`('urn');
+------------+---------+
| `KEY_NAME` | COUNTER |
+------------+---------+
| urn        |       3 |
+------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sEmVw1Es3tDD9KNhuG9yLw/2).

Check documentation [9.2.1 Identifier Qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I think the major mistake was using the same variable name like that of column name.